# Angular Typescript lib errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I have project recently upgraded from angular 9 to 11,

Works fine on my desktop.
When I pulled project from repo to my laptop (which was used with verions 9), I keep getting errors below when trying to compile. I updated global Angular CLI to 11.2.11 (the project is on 11.2.2) and Typescript to 4.1.5.

This is the error:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (11.2.11) is greater than your local version (11.2.2). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Building Angular Package
******************************************************************************   
It is not recommended to publish Ivy libraries to NPM repositories.
Read more here: https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility
******************************************************************************   

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'nine-gold-lib'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
⠙ Compiling TypeScript sources through NGCCompiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at __read (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:174:50)
    at Object.__spread (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:193:28)
    at Renderer.renderAdjacentStatements (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:159:63)
    at C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:80:52
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Renderer.renderFile (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:76:46)       
    at C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:53:84
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Renderer.renderProgram (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:48:54)    
    at Transformer.transform (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\packages\transformer.js:84:42)   
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:195:27)
    at C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:55:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:293:57)
    at step (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:124:57)
    at C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:117:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fwitk\Documents\GitHub\ninegoldplatform\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:287:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
× Compiling TypeScript sources through NGC
ERROR: NGCC failed.
```

Comment: Have you directly update angular version from 9 to 11 ? if Yes, then first you have to update project from version 9 to 10 and then version 10 to 11. Do not directly skip one major version when updating.

Comment: and double check in nine-gold-lib, every directives, pipes, services or components are exported too! if anything you had not exported from library and used it within you own module, then ivy will fail to compile library.

Comment: I did the update a few weeks ago on different machine. Did to 10 and then to 11. There were a few issues with libraries versions and it was resolved and package json has all the updates. Now on second machine I pulled the code from repo. I reinstalled on libraries on the project, but still getting these errors.

Comment: Sometimes deleting node_folder and reinstalling all using npm install may be solve issue

Comment: I tried. Didn't help

Comment: is repo is updated when you pull repo to your laptop ?

Comment: If repo is public, then can you share it here?

Comment: rebuild library after updating angular, and then install that library to angular may be work.. to tell Whats going wrong exactly is tough

Comment: https://github.com/GaurangDhorda/set-title-with-breadcrumbs/tree/master/projects/set-title-with-breadcrumbs I am sharing my library code with you. You can check all tsconfig and package.json file with my library, may be helpful to you..

Comment: Can you please, give package.json file of both project and library ? Lets see all the package version used inside project ?

Comment: Sorry @GaurangDhorda I was out, for some reason tslib was not updating based on package.json config, I had to do it manually.

Comment: Thats what about I asked in my last comment that to show package.json file. Glad You have find out your issues. One more thing You can use github-actions to crate CI/CD pipeline, which will run whenever any new pull request of push request comes to repo, github actions runs in background and reports you back that this repos is pass pipeline or not, so your code merge without conflict. :)

Comment: I have also UpVote your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with tslib version not updating based on package.json; after manual update the error disappeared.

Comment: What you update and how did you resolved that? Can you please explain more why is this happening?